# How to remove special comments in gulp clean-css?

Tags: gulp, gulp-clean-css, clean-css

How to remove special comments in gulp clean-css?

```
.pipe(cleancss({specialComments: 0}))
```

seems to have no effect

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you are using [the latest version](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css#level-1-optimizations), it should be `{level: {1: {specialComments: 0}}}`